# Whole mesh rotates with armature, not just the arms

Tags: armature

I want to only make the arms of my armature move so I added an armature and parent the mesh to the armature using automatic weight. However when I rotate the armature the whole mesh moved, not just the arms. (Mesh arm is already at a 90 degree angle, I want to bring it to the mouth)

Is it because i only have one armature? Do I have to do the whole body? Do anyone know how to fix this? I've inserted my blend file below

https://pasteall.org/blend/46f7daae2bb24d3fa65997dddea99977
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use automatic weight, Blender can only "take" what it has. Since there is only one bone in your armature, Blender takes all vertices to do it, so your whole person moves.

If you add bones like this:

[image]

it works:

[image]

blend file (but be aware, i just made "rough" bones, and just on one side to prove it works):
[image]

Comment: @PearlinKhoo Additionally to Chris' answer, if you only have a single bone I guess your stormtrooper doesn't even move at all - in _Pose Mode_. What you did is moving the object around with the armature in _Object Mode_. To move the arm you need to be in _Pose Mode_.

Comment: ohhh thanks so much. It helped me understand alot. However, when I open the file, my mesh is purple. I understand that theres a problem with the texture however I dont know hoe to fix it. Do you know how?

Comment: @PearlinKhoo if my answer was ok for you, please check the checkmark left from my answer. If you have another question, please start a new question. Thank you.